set angular required field if conditionally handle
here is my form:
initializePricingForm(): void {
    this.pricingForm = new FormGroup({
      price: new FormGroup({
        selling_type: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
          Validators.required
        ])),
        unit: new FormControl('pence'),
        unit_price: new FormControl(''),
        purchase_price: new FormControl(''),
        pack_purchase_price: new FormControl(''),
        weight_purchase_price: new FormControl(''),
        weight: new FormControl(''),
        weight_unit_price_measurement_type: new FormControl(''),
      }),

      currency: new FormControl('GBP'),
    });

    this.validationMessege();
    this.subs.sink = this.pricingForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.emitFormData();
    });

  }

if weight_purchase_price has value set weight & weight_unit_price_measurement_type must be required, only if weight_purchase_price has value. how to implement this?



// Custom validator function
function weightValidator(formGroup: FormGroup) {
  const weightPurchasePrice = formGroup.get('weight_purchase_price');
  const weight = formGroup.get('weight');
  const weightUnit = formGroup.get('weight_unit_price_measurement_type');

  if (weightPurchasePrice?.value) {
    if (!weight?.value || !weightUnit?.value) {
      return { required: true };
    }
  }

  return null;
}

initializePricingForm(): void {
  this.pricingForm = new FormGroup({
    price: new FormGroup({
      selling_type: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      unit: new FormControl('pence'),
      unit_price: new FormControl(''),
      purchase_price: new FormControl(''),
      pack_purchase_price: new FormControl(''),
      weight_purchase_price: new FormControl(''),
      weight: new FormControl(''),
      weight_unit_price_measurement_type: new FormControl(''),
    }, { validators: weightValidator }), // Apply the custom validator to the price group
    currency: new FormControl('GBP'),
  });

  this.validationMessege();
  this.subs.sink = this.pricingForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    this.emitFormData();
  });
}



Try this

it perfectly works but i changed few things will update your answer. @atikulislamatik

You can use addValidators() and removeValidators() to dynamically add or remove validators:
this.pricingForm.controls.price.controls.weight_purchase_price.valueChanges.subscribe(
  (value) => {
    if (value) {
      this.pricingForm.controls.price.controls.weight.addValidators(
        Validators.required
      );
      this.pricingForm.controls.price.controls.weight_unit_price_measurement_type.addValidators(
        Validators.required,
      );
    } else {
      this.pricingForm.controls.price.controls.weight.removeValidators(
        Validators.required,
      );
      this.pricingForm.controls.price.controls.weight_unit_price_measurement_type.removeValidators(
        Validators.required,
      );
    }
  },
);

Also make sure to unsubscribe from the subscription to prevent memory leaks.

Did you mean 'Validators'? Validators.required ?

Yes it was just a typo, fixed it @Shawn

I tried with this vai but not working required

@Shawn there was another issues with the wrong control being used, try again

its shows: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.

@Shawn cannot reproduce. With the current version, I am not getting any errors.
